# JSONB nested array query - check existence of attribute

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I want to check the existence of an attribute in a JSONB column using SQL.

Using this is I can check if attribute equals value:

```
SELECT count(*) AS "count" FROM "table" WHERE column->'node' @> '[{"Attribute":"value"}]'
```

What syntax do I use to check the existence of Attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'll check for null:

```
SELECT count(*) AS "count" FROM "table" 
WHERE column->'node'->'Attribute' is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

The `?` operator means [*Does the string exist as a top-level key within the JSON value?*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html) However, you want to check whether a key exists in a nested json array of objects, so you cannot use the operator directly. You have to unnest arrays.

Sample data:

```
create table my_table(id serial primary key, json_column jsonb);
insert into my_table (json_column) values
    ('{"node": [{"Attribute":"value"}, {"other key": 0}]}'),
    ('{"node": [{"Attribute":"value", "other key": 0}]}'),
    ('{"node": [{"Not Attribute":"value"}]}');
```

Use `jsonb_array_elements()` in a lateral join to find out whether a key exists in any element of the array:

```
select
    id,
    value,
    value ? 'Attribute' as key_exists_in_object
from my_table 
cross join jsonb_array_elements(json_column->'node')

 id |                 value                  | key_exists_in_object 
----+----------------------------------------+----------------------
  1 | {"Attribute": "value"}                 | t
  1 | {"other key": 0}                       | f
  2 | {"Attribute": "value", "other key": 0} | t
  3 | {"Not Attribute": "value"}             | f
(4 rows)
```

But this is not exactly what you are expecting. You need to aggregate results for arrays:

```
select
    id,
    json_column->'node' as array,
    bool_or(value ? 'Attribute') as key_exists_in_array
from my_table 
cross join jsonb_array_elements(json_column->'node')
group by id
order by id

 id |                   array                    | key_exists_in_array 
----+--------------------------------------------+---------------------
  1 | [{"Attribute": "value"}, {"other key": 0}] | t
  2 | [{"Attribute": "value", "other key": 0}]   | t
  3 | [{"Not Attribute": "value"}]               | f
(3 rows)
```

Well, this looks a bit complex. You can make it easier using the function:

```
create or replace function key_exists_in_array(key text, arr jsonb)
returns boolean language sql immutable as $$
    select bool_or(value ? key)
    from jsonb_array_elements(arr)
$$;

select
    id,
    json_column->'node' as array,
    key_exists_in_array('Attribute', json_column->'node')
from my_table 

 id |                   array                    | key_exists_in_array 
----+--------------------------------------------+---------------------
  1 | [{"Attribute": "value"}, {"other key": 0}] | t
  2 | [{"Attribute": "value", "other key": 0}]   | t
  3 | [{"Not Attribute": "value"}]               | f
(3 rows)
```